# Можно ли придать переменной значение case

Tags: php

Есть такой код, можно ли придать переменной **`$mystring`** значение **`case`**?

(что бы не писать повторно значение case в переменную **`$mystring`**

```
case "Hello World":

$mystring = 'Hello World';
$findme   = 'Hello';

$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if (false === $pos) {
    $m->msgSend("1", $user_id, $access_token);
} else {
    $m->msgSend("2", $user_id, $access_token);
}
```

Comment: Вы уже проверяете какую-то переменную в switch. Почему бы не использовать её?

Comment: @u_mulder, интересное предложение, спасибо.